# Access local filesystem from web browser (react)

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, electron

I am using this tool https://github.com/microsoft/VoTT. This tool is written in react/redux.

If the tool is running as web application, it does not have the option to access local file system (i.e., the computer that the browser is running). If the tool is running as an electron app, then the local system is accessible.

The question is more about how to allow the web app to access local file system.

Answer (score 2):

You've answered yourself in the question. :)

As it stands today (October 2020), there is not a standard API to access the file system from a web browser without using an extended "browser" (like Electron). There is however a [W3C Draft](https://wicg.github.io/file-system-access/) to add this capability to web browsers.